# How to filter out None from values in Dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, finance

After searching for the options in gives an output of "Strike Price", "Ask Price", "Bid Price" and "Implied Volatility".
However, I want to filter it so that it will only give me "implied volatility" above 1. Since "implied volatility" has some 'None' values in the dictionary it gives me an error:

"float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'"

```
import config 
import robin_stocks as r 

r.login(config.USERNAME,config.PASSWORD)

#specify criteria to search for options 

symbol = 'GE'
expirationDate = '2020-06-19'
strike = 8

#search for option given strike price, expiration date and symbol
#filter through low ask prices
#place order 


search_option = r.find_options_for_stock_by_expiration(symbol,expirationDate,optionType='call')
for option in search_option:
    if float(option['implied_volatility']) > 1:
        print("Strike Price: {}, Ask: {}, Bid: {}, IV: {}".format(option['strike_price'],option['ask_price'],option['bid_price'],option['implied_volatility']))'
```

Comment: This is way too much code for this question (remove lines until you have the least amount that shows your problem), at the same time the question in missing _the_ most important thing when asking about an error message in Python... the traceback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this condition in the `if`, as `None` is evaluated to `False` you don't need to do `if val is not None`, just `if val` is correct

```
if option['implied_volatility'] and float(option['implied_volatility']) > 1
```

---

Filter out the max `implied_volatility`

```
search_option = r.find_options_for_stock_by_expiration(...)
max_implied_volatility = max(float(option['implied_volatility'] or "-10000") for option in search_option) 

for option in search_option:

    if option['implied_volatility'] and \
       float(option['implied_volatility']) > 1 and \
       float(option['implied_volatility']) !=max_implied_volatility :

        print("Strike Price: {}, Ask: {}, Bid: {}, IV: {}".format(...))'
```

Comment: what about zero?

Comment: Thank you so much! And how can I filter out the max value from 'implied_volatility'?